# Unable to fix a Null Pointer Exception in Java

Tags: java

I have looked at this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and followed the answers. Yet the compiler is still complaining about a Null Pointer Exception. Here is my code blocks as to where the compiler is complaining:

```
public class readLogger {
    DLQPush dlqPush = new DLQPush();
    public String values[];
    int condition = 2;
    public BufferedReader reader = null;

public void readFile() {
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "/var/tmp/checkresults.log"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND!\n");
    }
    String str = null;
    try {
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (str.trim().length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            values = str.split("\t");
            System.out.println(values[1] + values[2]);
            classifyStatus();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The compiler is specifically complaining about this line:

```
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

And here is my Main class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
//import org.dcm4che3.tool.storescu.*;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readLogger rLog = new readLogger();
        rLog.readFile();
    }
}
```

I have made the necessary fixes described in the link to the previous questions, yet my compiler is still complaining about it:

```
ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at readLogger.readFile(readLogger.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Nevermind the ERROR as I have exported this to a JAR file and put it in Linux and yet it still throws a NullPointer in Linux. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix the NullPointer exception?

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated to us which line is line 25.

Comment: I updated it already, sorry

Comment: Nevermind the error ? It seems that your exception comes from here though.

Comment: str =  reader.readLine()
while(str!=null)    instead of 
while ((str =) != null) {, and tell us the difference

Comment: Ya know, this site sucks with it's voting process!

Comment: I'd say a single downvote for a question similar to this is actually doing surprisingly well.  Most questions about NPEs get downvoted to oblivion and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `reader` variable is `null` by the time you invoke `readLine` in statement: `while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {`, since the file is not found (see your own print statement).

Hence you throw a `NullPointerException` by invoking `readLine` on a `null` `BufferedReader` reference.

The best practice here would be to stop the execution of your `readFile` method if the file is not found.

As an alternative you might want to at least check for `null` before invoking instance methods on your `reader` variable.

Comment: I have changed it to, public BufferedReader reader; but it still states the same error..

Comment: Yep. Also mention that the execution continues after the first catch statement. He should probably remove it.

Comment: @ryekayo: That's because the file ain't there.